# How to change the progressmeter shape and image in xul?

Tags: xul

Default progressmeter shape is rectangular, is it possible to change the shape or add our own image for the progressmeter?

I need an arrow progressmeter, arrow should keep on filling when it progresses.

Comment: http://www.xul.fr/tutorial/progressmeter.html

Comment: Thanks. But my question is more specific. Can we change the rectagularity of a progressmeter in XUL?

Comment: Yes, you can. Please check the link it got an example & check with Mozilla website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/progressmeter

Comment: It did not help in anyway. Thanks for your effort. I appreciate it.

Comment: Please post your code, then we'll see.